# jQuery mobile makes everything smaller when rotating

Tags: jquery, iphone

I have a problem when I add my page to my home screen on my iPhone (this makes it appear like an app).

When I rotate my iPhone to landscap, all is fine.
But when I rotate back, text, sliders and everything is smaller.
And when I rotate to landscape, it gets even smaller - and back to vertical it gets even smaller... and finally it crashes.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "crashes" means? What happens?

Answer (score 0):

I think changing this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />`

To this maked it work:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`